# Convert String Array to JSON Array with custom format

Tags: jquery, json

I want to ask a question about converting a Array to a jsonArray. Here is my code to get jsonArray

```
[
  {id=10,job:computer, place:near}
  {id=11,job:computer2, place:near2}
  [   
    {id=14,job:computer, place:near3}  
    {id=11,job:computer2, place:near2}
    {id=10,job:computer2, place:near2}
  ],
  {id3=101,jobr:computerr, placer:nearr} 
  [   
    {id3=14,jobr:computerr, placre:nearrrr}             
  ],
]
```

I need this format json. But

```
var arr = 
[
  {
    id:'grid1',
    all:
    [    
      {id=14,job:computer, place:near3},   
      {id=11,job:computer2, place:near2},            
      {id=10,job:computer2, place:near2}
    ],
    change:
    [   
      {id=10,job:computer, place:near}
      {id=11,job:computer2, place:near2}
    ]   
  },
  {
    id:'grid2',
    all:
    [    
      {id3=14,jobr:computerr, placre:nearrrr}  
    ],
    change:
    [   
      {id3=101,jobr:computerr, placer:nearr}
    ]
  }
]
```

this my code use

```
obj = {};

$.each(cols[0].Values,function(key,value){
   obj[value.Value] = value.Display;
});
```

Comment: "I want to ask a question". That's good, but then you forgot to ask one.

Comment: Also: "Here is my code to get jsonArray". The section which follows that statement doesn't look like code to me.  It's not valid JSON, either. The example in "I need this format json" is also not valid JSON. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, or what your problem is. Please clarify the question. If you are having trouble with writing in clear English please consider asking someone to help you translate. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more guidance on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Rolled back your last edit (rev 6) because it vandalised my formatting fixes and included incomprehensible non-words.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this problem :

```
var coords=[]
  coords.push({ 'Id': $(myGrid)[0].id, 'ChangeRecord': coords2, 'all': gridData });
```